# Should I turn off a Tankless gas water heater during freezing weather if I cut water to the house during vacation

Tags: plumbing, water, water-heater, tankless, freezing

I will be away from home during freezing temperatures. I plan to cut the main water supply.  But, I have a Rheem tankless gas water heater on my outdoor wall.  If I cut the water supply, should I also cut the breaker to the tankless unit and shut off the gas and water?  I lost a tankless water unit last year because we lost power to the grid and everything froze.  I'm trying to avoid that problem this winter.   Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is the heater actually outdoors, or indoors fixed to an exterior wall? Will the heat be reduced or disabled such that freezing conditions could occur indoors?

Comment: Water and freezing temperatures never are good together.  Think most insurance require/expect you to have a person check on the house once a day in case of claims.  Would drain most of the water from pipes and any devices that hold water(toilets) if any chance of heat being off.

Answer (score 1):

> I lost a tankless water unit last year because we lost power to the grid and everything froze.

If you shut off the water then you have to make sure to drain the unit of any residual water.

Since your concern is freezing temperatures then you have to make sure to drain the unit of any water which could freeze and damage the unit.

Is it difficult to shut off the electric and gas to the unit? If not then just shut it off.

Answer (score 0):

If you cut off the water, then drain the tank and any other exposed water pipes. Also shut off the gas valve to the water heater.

If you feel lucky and do not intend to be gone very long, you could leave a hot water faucet open in the house somewhere...just a teeny, tiny bit... to keep water slowwwwwly flowing through the tank and water lines; an old-tyme solution to freezing temperatures and exposed water pipes.